# Let's Encrypt Root certificate expired on old Android tablet. How to fix?

Tags: https

I have an old Android tablet, and websites with Let's Encrypt SSL certificates no longer works.

[On Let's Encrypt's web site they basically just says it should still work](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/)
But in my case, it doesn't, I get "NET ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error. Date on the device is correct.

Does anyone know if there's a solution to this? Shouldn't it be possible to install the updated certificate manually? If so, exactly where can I download it, and how is it installed?

Comment: @Robert thanks, I guess it does answer it, in the way that the answer seemingly is "No, it's not possible to fix unless you have root" :-(

Comment: So your tablet is running Android 6 or 7.0? because otherwise you can simply install the rot CA certificate as user certificate. And if it is running 6 or 7 finding a vulnerability for rooting it should be easy.